# Integrated webcam not functioning properly 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, webcam

My integrated webcam is detected but isn't functioning properly.

```
nick@nick-Precision-7560:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5842 Broadcom Corp. 58200
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bcf:28c4 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0032 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

nick@nick-Precision-7560:~$ dmesg | grep 'Webcam\|uvcvideo\|1bcf'
[    1.588042] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=28c4, bcdDevice=86.16
[    1.588055] usb 3-3: Product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
[   11.789108] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.50 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (1bcf:28c4)
[   11.859441] input: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/input/input13
[   11.961074] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.50 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (1bcf:28c4)
[   11.977875] input: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.2/input/input14
[   11.977903] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

When I try to use the webcam with Cheese I see two cameras. The first gives me a black window. When I select the second I see the camera LED flash rapidly (2 Hz or so) and I see this image and it flickers:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first camera was giving me a black window because the camera has a physical cover. There is a slider on the top of the monitor that I wasn't aware of. When I slide that slider the second camera still gives me an image with a lot of bars across it but I can see an inverted black and white image which makes me think something is going on with the IR filter.